# How do I get an if statement to run after a variable has changed?

Tags: python, class, if-statement

Here is an example as to what I am doing:

```
class Something():
    def __init__(self):
        self.game = 0

something = Something()

if something.game == 0:
    # code is here
    if something happens:
        something.game = 1

if something.game == 1:
    # code is here
```

The problem is when something.game switches to 1, the second if statement doesn't run. I've switched the "if something.game == 1:" to elif but that isn't working either. I used a class system to avoid having to use global variables, but I have tried using global variables and it also didn't work.

Edit: The problem is the
`if something happens: something.game = 1`  part. something.game turns into a 1 (I think), but it won't do the other part of the code (the other part of the code meaning the second if statement:
"if something.game == 1:")

Comment: *Inside* the class you could use a `@property` and write a setter, so that you can run arbitrary code when the attribute is assigned to. It's not clear whether that's what you have in mind.

Comment: You could write a function for the second case and then simply point to it.

Comment: @ scenox thats what I normally do but I'm using Ursina and it doesn't run the update or render functions

Comment: Based on the code you provided you dont show that you are using Ursina. So based only on what you have shown this code will only ever run the first if statement and then exit since there is no other code after the if statements and no loop.

Comment: In your game, I think you want to make some code to be executed once based on a certain action, and during execution you do not want this code to start again in the loop of the game, is that true?

Comment: @Nour-AllahHussein Yes, I want it so that once a certain action happens, it will exit the  first if statement.